# Hide visibility of Ubuntu File Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, samba, ubuntu-11.10

I have a ubuntu Server 11.10.
I have setup SAMBA.

I'm using Mac and on the left panel of finder there is a heading called shared.
All the servers and computers that are connected on the network are shown there.

Is there a way on the ubuntu Server to disable the broadcast of it's availability so it doesn't show up as an active server. So You can only access it if you know the IP address

Answer (score 0):

You can set "browsable=no" at the share level or global level in your /etc/samba/smb.conf.
Ref: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#BROWSEABLE

You can also add a "$" to the end of the name of a share to hide it from Windows.